# Store extracted frame name inside an array - ffmpeg

Tags: c, arrays, image-processing, ffmpeg

I'm a complete newbie to C. I'm from PHP background, but it so happens that the code that I wrote in PHP needs to be converted to C. It was Java at first, but now the requirement is C.

After going through some tutorials, I got the basics of C and coded the following to run `ffmpeg.exe` from within a c program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

    char *app = "D:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe -i";
    char *input = " D:\\video.mpg";
    char *output = " D:\\frames\\image%d.jpg";
    char *param = " -r 10";
    char str[300];    
    snprintf(str, sizeof str, "%s%s%s%s", app, input, param, output);
    // str contains "D:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe -i D:\video.mpg -r 10 D:\frames"\image%d.jpg
    system(str); // <-- working fine, frames are being extracted
    /*
        do something here to store each extracted frame in an array
        so that the array contains image1.jpg, image2.jpg, image3.jpg...and so on
    */
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

On compiling and running the program, I'm getting the frames in the output folder as expected. The issue is I want to store each frame name inside an array as it gets extracted. So far, I haven't been able to come across a similar issue and so I decided to create a new thread for it. I'm hoping this is possible and would appreciate a nudge in the right direction.

Comment: does the command D:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe -i D:\video.mpg -r 10 D:\frames"\image%d.jpg      outputs the file name on stdout???

Comment: I'm not aware of `stdout`....it's use or how to use it

Comment: on screen/terminal, possibly you want all the filenames created as D:\frames\image%d.jpg in an array right???

Comment: As soon as the program is run, a dos window opens up and ffmpeg starts running....there seems to be a lot of information being shown each second..but I don't think the filename is being printed out in the dos window

Comment: Yes, either the file names or the entire path go into an array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now since the filenames are not displayed as output to system command using popen or fork will not work. I would recoomend you to perform a nftw on the output directory(D:\frames). It will list down all the files in the folder.

Sample code:
http://linux.die.net/man/3/nftw

Comment: Yeh. Actually this alternative crossed my mind. But the thing is while looping through the files from within a directory, the files are not pulled in correct ascending order. This is important because I need the array to contain files in an ascending order. Proper order - image1, image2, image3..and so on. Order shown when looping through directory - image1, image100, image101,..and so on

Comment: in that case just count all the files present in the folder. The filenames would be in sequence so you can create the filename at runtime. for example if there are 100 files then the in sequence filenames would be from image1 to image100

Comment: That's a good trick. But I assume `nftw` is linux based...whereas I'm on windows.

Comment: this code should work on windows also....   http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/libc/manual/html_node/Simple-Directory-Lister.html

Comment: I guess that would help. +1 btw